# How to implement this material card with flutter from material.io?

Tags: flutter

At material.io they have this standard anatomy of a material card:
https://material.io/design/components/cards.html#anatomy

[image: Material Card]

[image: Anatomy]

I was wondering how you would implement this in flutter and/or if there is some abstraction that I can use to make a card look like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
card -> column [
ListTile -> title, subtitle, leading,
Row -> expanded -> image.asset,
Row -> text,
Row mainaxisalignment: spacebetween ->  Row(buttons here as a child) , Row(Icons here as a child)
]
```

i have no time to write all code in flutter you can create it by use that

Answer (score 0):

The closest seems to be the Card class (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Card-class.html) together with a ListTile for the top part and card-themed buttons at the bottom, like in the example from that component's page.